# Roxy file manager in MVC doesn't accept session path

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, session, roxy-fileman

Hi guys i downloaded a file manager **http://www.roxyfileman.com** for my MVC project.So i added to my project and every thing works fine but every one can use this **product** i mean everyone can type the url and upload the file to my host !!!! this **filemanager** has a **json** config file as you can see here :

```
{
"FILES_ROOT":        "fileman/Uploads",
"SESSION_PATH_KEY":   "FileManager",
"THUMBS_VIEW_WIDTH":  "140",
"THUMBS_VIEW_HEIGHT": "120",
"PREVIEW_THUMB_WIDTH":"300",
"PREVIEW_THUMB_HEIGHT":"200",
"MAX_IMAGE_WIDTH":     "0",
"MAX_IMAGE_HEIGHT":    "0",
"INTEGRATION":       "tinymce3",
"DIRLIST":           "asp_net/main.ashx?a=DIRLIST",
"CREATEDIR":         "asp_net/main.ashx?a=CREATEDIR",
"DELETEDIR":         "asp_net/main.ashx?a=DELETEDIR",
"MOVEDIR":           "asp_net/main.ashx?a=MOVEDIR",
"COPYDIR":           "asp_net/main.ashx?a=COPYDIR",
"RENAMEDIR":         "asp_net/main.ashx?a=RENAMEDIR",
"FILESLIST":         "asp_net/main.ashx?a=FILESLIST",
"UPLOAD":            "asp_net/main.ashx?a=UPLOAD",
"DOWNLOAD":          "asp_net/main.ashx?a=DOWNLOAD",
"DOWNLOADDIR":       "asp_net/main.ashx?a=DOWNLOADDIR",
"DOWNLOADDIR":       "asp_net/main.ashx?a=DOWNLOADDIR",
"DELETEFILE":        "asp_net/main.ashx?a=DELETEFILE",
"MOVEFILE":          "asp_net/main.ashx?a=MOVEFILE",
"COPYFILE":          "asp_net/main.ashx?a=COPYFILE",
"RENAMEFILE":        "asp_net/main.ashx?a=RENAMEFILE",
"GENERATETHUMB":     "asp_net/main.ashx?a=GENERATETHUMB",
"DEFAULTVIEW":       "list",
"FORBIDDEN_UPLOADS": "zip js jsp jsb mhtml mht xhtml xht php phtml php3 php4 php5 phps shtml jhtml pl sh py cgi exe scr dll msi vbs bat com pif cmd vxd cpl htpasswd htaccess",
"ALLOWED_UPLOADS":   "jpg",
"FILEPERMISSIONS":   "0644",
"DIRPERMISSIONS":      "0755",
"LANG":              "auto",
"DATEFORMAT":        "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"
```

}

So as you can see the second part is **Session key**,so i add a session to my project when the users log in as you can see here :

```
   public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid && WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe))
        {
            Session.Add("FileManager",true);
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
        return View(model);
    }
```

So i added a session **FileManager** ,and i added to **json config file** .but it doesn't work .

Best regards
http://www.roxyfileman.com/install

Answer (score 2):

This is what I did to fix the program which I had the same issue.

in fileman ast_net folder modify main.ashx starting from line 201:

From:

```
protected string GetFilesRoot(){
    string ret = GetSetting("FILES_ROOT");
    if (_context.Session["SESSION_PATH_KEY"] != null)
        ret = (string)_context.Session[GetSetting("SESSION_PATH_KEY")];

    if(ret == "")
        ret = _context.Server.MapPath("../Uploads");
    else
        ret = FixPath(ret);
    return ret;
}
```

To:

```
protected string GetFilesRoot(){
    string ret = GetSetting("FILES_ROOT");

    if (GetSetting("SESSION_PATH_KEY") != null)
        ret = (string)_context.Session[GetSetting("SESSION_PATH_KEY")];

    if(ret == "")
        ret = _context.Server.MapPath("../Uploads");
    else
        ret = FixPath(ret);
    return ret;
}
```

in the conf.json i have left the FILES_ROOT variable empty and had set "SESSION_PATH_KEY":   "SESSIONFILEPATH"

in my login script where we set the session:
Session["SESSIONFILEPATH"] = "~/assests/1/";

From here you should be able to dynamically change your folder location which I am doing but for this example i just left it as is.

I did not MVC but this should work the same for it.

I hope it helps, if it does please vote =)

Cheers!